# How do I store images and information about those images in the iPhone memory and then load it?

Tags: ios, swift

I am a new programmer trying to create an iOS app which can track the movies and TV shows you have watched or plan to watch. So for example, If you have just finished a show you can add that show in to your "Already watched" list. And if you have a show that you want to watch you can add it to your "want to watch" list.

I want to have a view which will load images of the covers for the movies or TV show when the user opens the app and goes to the home view. Preferably in a random order.

Then I would like it so that when the use presses one of those images another view loads with info about that image. Do I have to create a view for each show or movie I store?

How do I go about storing info and images of these shows and movies on to the iOS device?

How do I get that stored info and images to load into the home view?

How do I get another view to load with info about that Image when it is pressed?

Comment: seems like you are expecting a complete tutorial. there is substantial information on the things you want to achieve in here: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/learn-ios-best-practices-by-building-a-simple-recipes-app-9bcbce4d10d

Answer (score 0):

So these are more of a 3 questions

- For the first 2 you will need to use a Database, CoreData or Realm or SQLite

Coredata
https://medium.com/xcblog/core-data-with-swift-4-for-beginners-1fc067cca707

Realm 
https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/

SQLite 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/385-sqlite-with-swift-tutorial-getting-started

Most of apps now go with Realm i think you may learn it faster if you are too new

- To Pass data you can use [Delegate](https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef) or check this [article](https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/)

Comment: Thank you very much. I have decided to use CoreData